# How is omp_get_thread_num implemented?

Tags: openmp

I am curious how it works, since this function is called without parameters, how does it find out which thread actually called it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What follows is specific to GNU's OpenMP runtime library [`libgomp`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/tags/gcc_4_8_2_release/libgomp/), but other OpenMP runtimes do more or less the same. All links lead into the relevant parts of the GCC 4.8.2 source code.

The actual implementation of [`omp_get_thread_num()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/tags/gcc_4_8_2_release/libgomp/parallel.c?revision=203690&view=markup#l146) is very simple:

```c
int
omp_get_thread_num (void)
{
  return gomp_thread ()->ts.team_id;
}
```

Each thread has a thread-local pointer to an instance of [`struct gomp_thread`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/tags/gcc_4_8_2_release/libgomp/libgomp.h?revision=203690&view=markup#l337). Also each thread is part of a team of threads and its state inside the team is represented by the `ts` member of type [`struct gomp_thread_team_state`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/tags/gcc_4_8_2_release/libgomp/libgomp.h?revision=203690&view=markup#l177). The latter contains an `unsigned int` member called `team_id` which gives the ID of the thread in its team.

The way the thread locates its own instance of `struct gomp_thread` depends on whether the platform has TLS (thread-local storage) or not. In the latter case the TLS is emulated by the POSIX threads library. Both implementations are: (taken from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/tags/gcc_4_8_2_release/libgomp/libgomp.h?revision=203690&view=markup#l373))

with TLS:

```c
extern __thread struct gomp_thread gomp_tls_data;
static inline struct gomp_thread *gomp_thread (void)
{
  return &gomp_tls_data;
}
```

The `__thread` keyword makes the global variable `gomp_tls_data` thread-local, which means that each thread gets its own copy of it.

without TLS:

```c
extern pthread_key_t gomp_tls_key;
static inline struct gomp_thread *gomp_thread (void)
{
  return pthread_getspecific (gomp_tls_key);
}
```

In that case the `pthread_getspecific()` is used to obtain a thread-local copy of the structure instance (located [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/tags/gcc_4_8_2_release/libgomp/team.c?revision=203690&view=markup)).

Though it is possible that `pthread_getspecific()` also uses the TLS to store the values and one might wonder why two different implementations are provided, the answer is that directly accessing the TLS could be faster than calling the Pthreads API functions. In that respect OS X is a peculiar case - the Mach-O executable format does not provide a GNU compatible TLS implementation and some people have reported that there the Pthreads API is actually faster than the emulated GNU TLS.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear answer. But there's still something I don't understand : shouldn't omp_get_thread_num be a static inline function like gomp_thread ? If it this not, this function will be externally linked, so when omp_get_thread_num is compiled, the gomp_thread is not our thread-specific version of gomp_thread (by thread-specific I mean the expanded inline function where gomp_tls_data reference our local copy).

Comment: Shared objects can hold global data elements that are merged into the TLS by the RTLD. The details are complicated, but in a nutshell - dynamic-link libraries (like `libgomp.so`) can have thread-local versions of their own symbols and therefore regular (not inlined) functions like `omp_get_thread_num()` can access those thread-local global symbols in the context of the calling thread.

Comment: Thanks, I see now, it is not static linking but dynamic linking at run-time(like Windows DLLs), so the symbols can change at each call.

Comment: It works with static libraries too - their thread-local sybols are put in the executable's TLS.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, that's not specified, so I can't give a general answer. GCC uses a structure to manage threads, which has the [`__thread` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Thread-Local.html). I guess the implementation in other compilers will be similar.

The documentation links to a PDF which explains how TLS (Thread local storage) works: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf